# how can compile and execute java file in php?

Tags: java, php

I have two file.

1. Hello.java
2. Index.php

**Hello.java**

```
class Hello
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("HelloWorld");
    }
}
```

**Index.php**

```
$file="Hello.java";
exec('javac'.$file,$output,$resultCode);
if ($resultCode===0)
{
    echo "Result: " . $resultCode . "\n";
}
else
{
    echo "fail";
}
```

It give "Fail" output i want to get "HelloWorld" output on browser.
please help me.

Comment: you have not placed a space between the javac command and the rest of the arguments.

Comment: By just executing `javac Hello.java` you will get the output of the Java compiler. Execute `java -cp . Hello` to get the output of the actual program.

Answer (score 3):

You have not provided a space between your command and arguments.

```
exec('javac'.$file,$output,$resultCode);
```

should be

```
exec('javac '.$file,$output,$resultCode);
```

This part just completed the compiling then you need another `exec` statement to completed the execution of the program. As suggested by [mthmulders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1523342/mthmulders)

```
exec("java -cp . Hello", $output,$resultCode);
```